# Efficient vapply with global assign

Tags: r

I have data like the example below with multiple categorical variables and a continuous variable. I want to find the last instance of a record in the continuous variable for each grouping of the categorical variables and then add that to the dataset as a new column. My data set has a couple million rows and I'm trying to find out if anyone has a more efficient method. I am using `apply` instead of loops but its still pretty slow. Thanks in advance.

reproducible example:

```
require(tidyr)
data(iris)

g.iris <- gather(iris, key=key, value=value, -Species)
g.iris$time <- rep(1:50, 12)

index.vector <- paste(g.iris$Species, g.iris$key, sep=" - ")
index.vector <- index.vector[!duplicated(index.vector)]

vapply(index.vector, FUN.VALUE=numeric(1), function(x) {

group <- g.iris[g.iris$Species == gsub("(^.+)( - )(.+$)", "\\1", x) &
                    g.iris$key == gsub("(^.+)( - )(.+$)", "\\3", x), ]

value <- group[max(group$time), "value"]

g.iris[g.iris$Species == group$Species &
       g.iris$key == group$key, "last.value"] <<- value

})
```

Comment: `apply` family functions ARE loops. Their benefits include modularity and operating in a protected environment. They are not necessarily "faster" than well constructed for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a simple `dplyr` command

```
xx <- g.iris %>% group_by(Species, key) %>% 
  mutate(last.value=value[which.max(time)])
```

Seems to return the same thing as your code but doesn't bother with the `index.vector` part at all.

```
all(xx$last.value == g.iris$last.value)
# [1] TRUE
```